# QUnit asynchronizity and browser unresponsiveness

Tags: qunit

I'm wondering how it is possible that a QUnit test suite, with lots of test cases, can ever make the browser window become unresponsive. Shouldn't the asynchronous execution of the tests ensure that the browser frequently is left room to breathe?

Comment: Do you have a specific question here? Or problem you're having? This isn't really a question about code and isn't something likely to get a good answer.

Comment: well, the unresponsiveness is problematic. If it grows further, as my test suite grows, Firefox will start popping up a dialogue box complaining that the sites script is unresponsive.